# NHibernate on Azure?

Tags: c#, nhibernate, azure

Has anyone tried NHibernate on Azure? Is there conflicts with the medium trust or SQL integration?

Comment: I'm going to have to try this, let us know what you find out too

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The NHibernate test suite [fully works on SQL Azure](http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2009/09/05/nhibernate-on-the-cloud-sql-azure.aspx).  You should be able to simply change your connection string to your SQL Azure connection string.

There shouldn't be any hangups in running using NHibernate from a Web or Worker role.

Comment: Until Sharding is implemented, you will be stuck with the 1GB (or is it 10?) limit.

Comment: You can have either a 1 GB or 10 GB database currently.

Comment: Definitely an old thread, but SQL Azure forcibly closes connection, which the connection pool doesn't pick up.  NHibernate doesn't pick it up either, which means at random points, NHibernate will try to execute queries on a closed connection.  I haven't found an elegant work around for this yet.

Answer (score 6):

I have tried NHibernate 3 inside Azure Web Role which talks to Azure SQL. 
I did not have any problems, runs pretty fine.

I am using NFluent for configuration. I can create the database directly from the mapping configuration.

There was only one issue with the HiLo generator. If you are interested in details, I have [post it on my blog](http://www.hoonzis.com/nhibernate-nfluent-and-custom-hilo/).

This issue comes from the fact that Azure SQL is not completely compatible with SQL Server. The limitations of Azure SQL are [described here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee336245.aspx).
But that was just a minor issue.

Answer (score 4):

Not sure about NHibernate, but Azure now allows full trust applications.

[Hosting Web and Worker Roles Under Full Trust](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd573353.aspx)